# To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher

Tags: ssis

When executing the SSIS package using C# reference(Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS) getting above mentioned error. I also installed the Integration Services

Comment: @billinkc SQL server intergration service 14.0 installed and running

Comment: @billinkc got the solution, thanks for reply. I imported the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll from wrong path . Right path was : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91